# What does "you can now tap ambient magical fields" mean?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

This just popped up seemingly randomly on my HuWz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to **tap ambient magical fields** is granted by worshipping Sif Muna.  Like all abilities, it is activated via pressing the <kbd>a</kbd> button and then selecting the ability.  When activated, you instantly regain a small amount of mana, but you become more hungry.  It is mainly used when you are out of mana, but are in a tight situation and cannot spend any time resting to regain it.

The CrawlWiki has all [the gory details](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/index.php?title=Channel_energy).  The formula for the actual amount of food lost doesn't help much during a game, since you never know your precise food level.  However, the important information is that your **Invocations** skill and **Intelligence** stat control how likely the ability is to succeed, while just your **Invocations** skill controls how much mana you gain.

Comment: Ah! Okay. Could you clarify a bit before I accept your answer? At the cost of food how? Does it simply passively work by regenerating more of my mana when I'm hungry? Thanks!

Comment: Found it: http://crawl.chaosforge.org/index.php?title=Channel_energy

Answer accepted. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.